# Open Seed for Crawl

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I am currently running a crawl of the internet using [Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/). This requires a list of URLs to start as a seed. I currently have a 500k url seed.

But I am looking for any open data sources to provide good starting seeds for web crawls.

Comment: What are your requirements for the seed? Are you interested in a specific area of the web?

Comment: Spcific top would be "places"

And that other question was mine. This question is different as I am looking for a Seed list, and not a crawl dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the [top 1 million (ZIP)](http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip) sites from [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/topsites).

Comment: [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/) offers a [free download of their top million US sites](https://ak.quantcast.com/quantcast-top-million.zip) as well. It should also be noted that both downloads are very likely not Open Data. However, for seeding a web crawler, free (as in beer) should probably be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the Common Crawl dataset: http://commoncrawl.org/

It's hosted on Amazon s3 as HDFS with a 'pay as you access' model.

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I am using the seed to create my own web crawl because common crawl coverage is not great.